How to display images embedded in Dyn365 email body in PowerApps
In PowerApps, i look up an email message in the Email Messages table of my Dyn365 instance and i put the body of that email into a 'HTML text' control --> the text of the email body displays OK but the embedded images do not. Instead of the image, i see an empty frame with a 'broken reference' icon in top left corner.
So i’ve been doing some research into this over the past few hours and i now understand that i will need to first pull the image from Azure Blob Storage into the app before i can display it - is that correct? And if so, can i still do it if i do not know any of the client id, account name, tenant, etc. that the Azure Blob Storage connector asks me to provide when i try to add it to my app?


i now understand that i will need to first pull the image from Azure Blob Storage into the app before i can display it - is that correct?And if so, can i still do it if i do not know any of the client id, account name, tenant, etc. that the Azure Blob Storage connector asks me to provide when i try to add it to my app?

You are right; you have to first fetch the picture into the app from Azure Blob Storage in order for the embedded photos to appear in the email body.
In order to use the Azure Blob Storage connector, you will need to provide the required information such as client id, account name, and tenant.
Here is the MS-Document to connect Azure Blob Storage with Power Apps.
It will show the authentication of Microsoft Entera ID and managed identity.
Request
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?<sas token>


The above request will get the image from blob storage using sas token. You can get the sas token from the Azure portal.
If you don’t have any info, check with a different storage account which doesn’t have any level of authentication.
Reference:

Connect to Azure Blob Storage from Power Apps - Power Apps | Microsoft Learn
Get Blob (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn


thank you, @Naveen Sharma, very helpful!
